# dynamic value is null because of Jobject filled with base64 encoded files

Tags: c#, vb.net, json.net, base64, asp.net-web-api2

I have a VB.net application that need to call a C# web api with some parameters, including a lot of base64 encoded files.

I found out that the best way to pass this data to the application is to create a JObject with all data and pass to the WebAPI so it can read as a dynamic object

thats the vb.net "front end"

```
Dim jObj As JObject = New JObject From {
            {"Field1", "foo"},
            {"Field2", "foo"},
            {"ListFileFotoBase64", JToken.FromObject(lstFileFotoBase64)}
        }

 Dim uri As New Uri(Url & $"WebApiMethod")
        Using client As HttpClient = New HttpClient
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token)

            Dim content As StringContent = New StringContent(jObj.ToString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

            Using response As HttpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result
                Dim res As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                Dim httpResponse As HttpResponseCustom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of HttpResponseCustom)(res)
                Return httpResponse
            End Using
        End Using
```

lstFileFotoBase64 is a list of strings that can contain up to 100 base64 encoded files

and thats how I read in the C# WebApi Project:

```
 [Route("WebApiMethod")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseCustom))]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult WebApiMethod(dynamic value)
    {

        try
        {
              List<string> ListFileFotoBase64 = ((JArray)value.ListFileFotoBase64).ToObject<List<string>>();
```

the problem is that if I load 61 elements of lstFileFotoBase64 the whole dynamic object is null, but if I remove lstFileFotoBase64 from the JObject it works normally.
I always pass a base64 encoded file to the webapi and I encounter no problems.

Thanks in advice

Comment: "if I load 61 elements of lstFileFotoBase64 the whole dynamic object is null" - does it work for other quantities?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it looks like that if i load for example just one element it works